# Change of Dependent Variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I have perhaps a simple question but I have to be sure:

I have a differential equation in form of:
$$\dfrac{\partial y(t,x)}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(v(t,x)y(t,x)\right)=S(t,x,y)$$

Now I want to change the dependent variable from $$y(t,x)$$ to $$k(t,x)$$ with:
$$y(t,x)=\dfrac{k(t,x)}{a(t,x) b(t,x)}$$

How do I perform this change exactly?
My proposal is:
$$\dfrac{\partial k(t,x)}{\partial t}\dfrac{1}{a(t,x) b(t,x)}-\dfrac{\partial a(t,x)}{\partial t}\dfrac{k(t,x)}{a^{2}(t,x) b(t,x)}-\dfrac{\partial b(t,x)}{\partial t}\dfrac{ k(t,x)}{ a(t,x) b^{2}(t,x)}+ \dfrac{\partial k(t,x)}{\partial x}\dfrac{ v(t,x)}{a(t,x) b(t,x)}-\dfrac{\partial a(t,x)}{\partial x}\dfrac{v(t,x)k(t,x)}{a^{2}(t,x) b(t,x)}-\dfrac{\partial b(t,x)}{\partial x}\dfrac{v(t,x) k(t,x)}{ a(t,x) b^{2}(t,x)}+\dfrac{\partial v(t,x)}{\partial x}\dfrac{ k(t,x)}{ a(t,x) b(t,x)}=S(t,x,\dfrac{k(t,x)}{a(t,x) b(t,x)})$$

Multiplying both sides by $$a(t,x)b(t,x)$$ and using the material time derivative $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \phi(t,x)}{\mathrm{d} t}= \dfrac{\partial \phi(t,x)}{ \partial t }+v(t,x)\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$$ it result's:

$$\dfrac{\partial k(t,x)}{\partial t} +\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(v(t,x)k(t,x))-\dfrac{k(t,x)}{a(t,x)}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} a(t,x)}{\mathrm{d} t}-\dfrac{k(t,x)}{b(t,x)}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} b(t,x)}{\mathrm{d} t}=a(t,x) b(t,x)S(t,x,\dfrac{k(t,x)}{a(t,x) b(t,x)})$$

Is this transformation done correctly?
And do you have a good source?

Comment: On the second line after 'My proposal is:' surely you should have some partial derivatives w.r.t $x$? It seems like they appear in your answer but not your workings.

Comment: It was a typo I fixed it

Comment: And if I'm reading this correctly you are substituting using the material time derivative for the term $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ even though its just a partial derivative?

Comment: The original pde origins from some flow problem. And I use the material time derivative just for $a(t,x)$ and $b(t,x)$ for a more compact notation.

Comment: There shouldn't be any partial derivative multiplied by partial derivative terms involved.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Hello thanks for your comments, now all typos should be gone. Now the question remains is this correct? Because according to wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20change%20of,to%20a%20better%20understood%20problem.
the mapping should be bijective. The above subsitution should not be bijective or ?
Because the same value $y$ can be obtained for different combinations of $a$ and $b$ for a value of $k$.